# Messing with jquery produced an unexpected outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before reading, please note I am a beginner in terms of jquery, html, and css.

Before installing jquery into my site, I had a header and footer in fixed positions such that they stuck to the top and bottom of the browser. When I installed jquery, the header and footer dissapeared for some reason. The jquery functions work fine as I tested it with my functions. Anyone have any insight on why my header and footer dissapear while using jquery? Thanks:

Ignore most of the code, just look at this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w1bpmkn5/

**Html:**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**css:**

```
.header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: 1a1a1a;
    z-index: 100;
}

.footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px; 
    background-color: 1a1a1a;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**jquery (script.js) if needed:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
    $(".box").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    });
});
```

Comment: pls give as a fiddle code

Comment: use the firebug tool and check the html and css styles for your header and footer

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle and let us know what seems to be the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w1bpmkn5/

Comment: are you sure that jQuery is correctly loaded? Is the path right?

Comment: Where is the `element having box class`?

Comment: It seems the code you gave posted is not enough to reproduce the problem. Making a JsFiddle reproducing the problem would be great. Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: I suggest you not to use `width: 100%` but `right: 0` in your header/footer css.

Comment: I suggest using CSS animations instead. Much more efficient and easily changed: http://jsfiddle.net/2j38shac/

Comment: I added the jsfiddle, sorry guys! and I'm using firefox, latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the `box` class like this:

```
<div class="header box">Header</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

mouseenter is now working. Check this in: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s2agfdjz/)

Comment: I tried that and it does seem to work, I added a jsfiddle link as requested (sorry guys, new to this jsfiddle is the easiest way I guess haha). The problem I'm still having is the background color for the header and footer don't appear when I use jquery. The text "Header" and "Footer" do appear though. I need the background color to appear more then anything. Thanks!

Comment: you are missing the `#` before the color. check the updated: http://jsfiddle.net/w1bpmkn5/1/

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I made such a simple mistake.